# How to connect to SQL Server using ASP.NET MVC web application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to connect to SQL Server from my ASP.NET MVC application in Visual Studio. I type the following connection string in the `web.config` file:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="EmploymentDbContext" 
        connectionString="Data Source=ASD-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EmploymentsHistory;Integrated Security=SSPI ;" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

My server name is `ASD-PC\SQLEXPRESS` and I use Windows Authentication to connect to SQL Server.

When I run the ASP.NET MVC project the project runs with success but the database `EmploymentsHistory` isn't there. How to fix that?

Comment: Well ... did you *create* the database on the server? It's not just going to magically appear....

Comment: I'm expecting the Entitiy Framework to do the job by making EmploymentDbContext with DbSet in it and the connection string I've just passed.

Comment: Do you make a call to context.Initialize(false) when the app starts?

Comment: Where do I have to put that. And what exactly do I have to put?

Comment: Well, you should **mention** that you're using Entity Framework and assume it'll generate the database in your original question ....

Comment: @TheoWallcot12 - I generally put it where the application starts, like Main() in a console app, or in the Global.asax file using(var ctx = new EmploymentDbContext){ ctx.Database.Initialize(false); }  Also, make sure your EF config is setup properly in the web.config.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, works for me. Remember to insert database name.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="EmploymentDbContext"
connectionString="server =ASD-PC\SQLEXPRESS; database=DATABASENAME; integrated security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: The same shit...The database isn't there. :(

Comment: Have you tried to connect to the database using another type of application? and you use Entity framework right?

Comment: No I haven't tried connecting to SQL Server database yet. I've always used LocalDB. Yes I'm using Entity Framework.

Comment: Connection string is correct. Which approach you are using of Entity Framework. Code first or Database first or Model first.

Comment: Code first approach.

Answer (score 1):

Code First Approach - You just need to write a code in model after that database and tables will be created. I hope, you have added Entity Framework library in your application.
Below is the example of first creating database by using "Code First Approach" after that you can easily do CRUD operation.

First create a model.
Ex.

```
public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id{get;set;}
        [Required]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string surname { get; set; }
    }

public class personContext : DbContext
    {
        public personContext()
            : base("EmploymentDbContext")
        {
            //If model change, It will re-create new database.
            Database.SetInitializer<personContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<personContext>());
        }
        public DbSet<Person> person { get; set; }
   }
```

Use below code in controller or in any .cs file to only create a database.

```
using (var ctx = new personContext())
            {
                ctx.Database.Create();
            }
```